# Bootstrap in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I already read a lot of post about bootstrap in IE7 but I don't find solution how to fix it. My main problem is grid because of wrong grid all website is messed up.

Can you someone help me how to fix grid in IE7?

Thanks for help :)

[image]

Comment: Not concrete question. What exactly the problem is ? You can also share some screenshots here  for better understanding.

Comment: please look there http://mf.ipar.cz or there is screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3mdywN_3UIEd3JORUpIbll1ZGxIcVBUdnp3LTgzTFozRXhv/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: as you can see header is showing wrong

Comment: please post the image in your question.

Comment: I edit my first post and add screenshot.